# Let $D^2 =\{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $\mathbb{R}^2/D^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $D^2 =\{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. let $D^2$ be the closed disk of radius $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to show that the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^2/D^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to show this explicitly.

If I'm understanding correctly, I could also say that we are trying to show that $\mathbb{R}^2/\sim $ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, where the equivalence relation $\sim$ is given by:

$(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2) \iff$ either $[(x_1,y_1) \in D^2$ and $(x_2,y_2) \in D^2$] or $(x_1,y_1) = (x_2,y_2)$.

I guess I want to find a continuous map from $\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ that preserves equivalence classes, but I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does $\mathbb{R}^2 / D^2$  mean? Did you perhaps mean $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus D^2$?

Comment: @copper.hat I am referring to the quotient space

Comment: I think he means the quotient set induced by the relation he wrote

Comment: Try scaling along straight lines through origin. The disk maps to $0$ and any point outside the disk has a straight line passing through the origin; scale it toward the origin based on how far from the disk the point is (so closer to the disk will be mapped closer to the origin).

Comment: Map $D^2$ to $0$ and $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus D^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: If you find a continuous and bijective map $g$ from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ it follows, for the universal property of quotient, that $\exists \bar g: \mathbb{R^2} /D^2 \to \mathbb{R^2}$ continuous and bijective whose inverse $\bar \pi$ is continuous. Have you ever seen the homeomorphism with $S^1$? In any case you cold consider the isomorphism between $\mathbb{R^2}$  
 and $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 2):

Define
$$f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2, f(p) = \begin{cases} 0 &  \lVert p \rVert \le 1 \\  \frac{\lVert p \rVert -1}{\lVert p \rVert} p & \lVert p \rVert \ge 1 \end{cases}$$
This is a continuos map such that $f^{-1}(0) = D^2$ and $f^{-1}(q)  = \{ \frac{\lVert q \rVert +1}{\lVert q \rVert}q \}$ for $q \ne 0$. In particular $f$ is a surjection. Moreover, $f$ is closed map: Let $A \subset \mathbb R^2$ be closed. and $(q_n)$ be a sequence in $f(A)$ converging to some $q \in \mathbb R^2$. Choose $p_n \in A$ such that $f(p_n) = q_n$. If infinitely many $p_n \in D^2$, we find a subsequence $(p_{n_k})$ converging to some $p \in D^2$. Sinced $A$ is closed, $p \in A$. Then $q  = \lim_n q_n = \lim_k q_{n_l} = \lim_k f(p_{n_l}) = f(p) \in f(A)$. Now let only finitely many $p_n \in D^2$. Throwing these away, we may assume w.l.o.g that all $p_n \notin D^2$. Then $\lVert p_n \rVert -1 = \lVert f(p_n) \rVert = \lVert q_n \rVert \to \lVert q \rVert$. Thus $(p_n)$ is bounded and we find a subsequence $(p_{n_k})$ converging to some $p \in \mathbb R^2$. Clearly $p \in A$ and as above we see that $q \in f(A)$.

As a closed map, $f$ is a quotient map. It induces a bijection $h : \mathbb R^2/D^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $h \circ r = f$ ($r : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2/D^2$ is the quotient map). This $h$ is automatically a homeomorphism. See [When is a space homeomorphic to a quotient space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3064037)