# Show that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $U$ = $\{z \in \mathbb{C}\mid \vert z \vert = 1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

We are told to show that the quotient group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the group $U$ = $\{z \in \mathbb{C}\mid \vert z \vert = 1\}$ endowed with multiplication as operation.

My answer:

The group $U$ symbolizes the unit circle. Euler's formula gives an isomorphism from an previous assignment as $z = e^{i2\pi r}$. We also showed that $\phi:\mathbb{R} \longmapsto \mathbb{C}$ is a homomorphism. The equation for that was $\phi(r)=\cos (2\pi r) + i \sin (2\pi r)$. Plotting Euler's formula on an imaginary-real axis gives us a circle. Here $r = 1$ (as seen on the kernel since $\epsilon = 1$). This indicates that it is isomorphic to $U$. $\mathbb{Z}$ is just any set of integers and will only make the values smaller and thereby into the unit circle.

What do you think of my answer?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Will take that into account. Do you have anything to say about my answer?

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495924/how-does-the-quotient-mathbbr-mathbbz-become-the-circle-s1

Answer (score 4):

So what you want to say  is something like that $\psi:\Bbb R\to  U$ by $\psi(r)=e^{2\pi i r}$ induces an isomorphism between $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ and $U$.  Here $U$ is the circle group.  This is true by the first isomorphism theorem, since $\operatorname{ker}\psi=\Bbb Z$.

This is true.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this. But how do I prove that ker ø = Z?

Comment: @HomerSimpson $e^{2 \pi i r} = \cos(2\pi r ) + i \sin(2 \pi r) = 1$ exactly when $r$ is an integer.  You probably don't need to say more than that - basic facts about trig should be free to use.